# SQL Server 2008 query 1 row date convert into column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My query is

```
SELECT 
   UB.UnitID as UnitID, UB.Name as Unit, US.UnitID as UnitID, US.Name as Unit,
   UP.UnitID as UnitID, UP.Name as Unit
FROM 
   Product PR 
INNER JOIN
   Unit UB on UB.UnitID = PR.BaseUnitID 
INNER JOIN
   Unit US on US.UnitID = PR.SecondaryUnitID 
INNER JOIN
   Unit UP on P.UnitID = PR.PrimaryUnitID 
where 
   Productid = 1
```

Output:

```
BaseUnitID   BaseUnit   SecondaryUnitID    SecondaryUnit   PrimaryUnitID   PrimaryUnit
----------   -------    ----------------   ------------   -------------   ------------
     1       PCS               2           CTN                   3         TRAY
```

SQL query convert into this form

```
UnitID    Unit
------    ----
  1       PCS
  2       CTN
  3       TRAY
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the query in the edited version of your question, you can do what you want using `or` or `in` in the join condition:

```
SELECT U.UnitID as UnitID, U.Name as Unit
FROM Product PR inner join
     Unit U
     on U.UnitID in (PR.BaseUnitID, PR.SecondaryUnitID, PR.PrimaryUnitID)
where Productid = 1;
```

this is correct query

Answer (score 2):

I don't sure that it is what you need but maybe it can help you.

```
SELECT BaseUnitID UnitID, BaseUnit Unit FROM tbl UNION ALL
SELECT SecondaryUnitID, SecondaryUnit FROM tbl UNION ALL
SELECT PrimaryUnitID, PrimaryUnit FROM tbl
```

Comment: +1 . . . But I think it is a good idea to always use `as` for column aliases.

Comment: my query is 
--------


SELECT UB.UnitID as UnitID,UB.Name as Unit,US.UnitID as UnitID,US.Name as Unit,UP.UnitID as UnitID,UP.Name as Unit
 FROM Product PR 
inner join Unit UB on UB.UnitID=PR.BaseUnitID 
inner join Unit US on US.UnitID=PR.SecondaryUnitID 
inner join Unit UP on UP.UnitID=PR.PrimaryUnitID